# conference name in "palette quaternary"

Tags: beamer

For a conference presentation, I have added conference name inside \date as

```
\date[conf-name]{conference long name 2013}
```

So, "conference long name 2013" is coming at the title page.
So good so far.
But I also want the short name to appear at the bottom of each page, I mean in quaternary position, instead of the title of my talk.

I am using

```
\mode<presentation>
{
\usetheme{Darmstadt}
\usetheme{Warsaw}
\setbeamercovered{transparent}
}
```

How can I do that?
Edit: bolt from the blue: I have added `\title[conf-name]{title}` to have this effect.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can redefine the `footline` template used by the `split` outer theme to use `\insertshortdate` instead of the default `\insertshorttitle`:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\mode<presentation>
{
\usetheme{Darmstadt}
\usetheme{Warsaw}
\setbeamercovered{transparent}
}

\makeatletter
\setbeamertemplate{footline}
{%
  \leavevmode%
  \hbox{\begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=.5\paperwidth,ht=2.5ex,dp=1.125ex,leftskip=.3cm plus1fill,rightskip=.3cm]{author in head/foot}%
    \usebeamerfont{author in head/foot}\insertshortauthor
  \end{beamercolorbox}%
  \begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=.5\paperwidth,ht=2.5ex,dp=1.125ex,leftskip=.3cm,rightskip=.3cm plus1fil]{title in head/foot}%
    \usebeamerfont{title in head/foot}\insertshortdate
  \end{beamercolorbox}}%
  \vskip0pt%
}
\makeatother

\title{Title of the talk}
\date[conf-name]{conference long name 2013}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\maketitle
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]